# C# vs Python query against SQLite database

Tags: c#, python, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a SQLite database that has a single table with 18 million rows and 24 columns. The schema is along the lines of,

```
Date (VARCHAR)
CompanyName (VARCHAR)
Amount (REAL)
AggCode (VARCHAR)
Level1 ... Level20 (VARCHAR)
```

I am querying the table two ways - first with a Python script, and then with a C# function that is exposed to Excel with ExcelDNA (ultimately I'd prefer to use Excel to run the queries as some queries will return rows of data that need to be further manipulated).

I find that Python usually outperforms the Excel add-in by a factor of 3-5x, and I was wondering if there was something wrong with my code. Sample query below,

```
query = "SELECT Sum(Amount) FROM my WHERE Level9='STIN_J' AND (AggCode='R_REAL' AND Date='05DEC2016')"
```

The queries are usually run combining the fields `Level9`, `Level5`, `AggCode`, `Date`, `CompanyName` in the `WHERE` clause. So apart from the raw table, I have also configured the following four indices,

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 on my(Level09, AggCode);
CREATE INDEX idx2 on my(Level05, AggCode);
CREATE INDEX idx3 on my(CompanyName, AggCode);
CREATE INDEX idx4 on my(Date, AggCode);
```

This is the sample Python code to run a query,

```
import sqlite3 as lite
...
con = lite.connect("C:\temp\my.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchall
for row in data:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        print row[i],
    print "\t",
```

On the whole this code works rather well.

This is the sample C# code to run a query,

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
...
string constr = "Data Source=C:\temp\my.db;Version=3;";
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(constr);
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);                
conn.Open();
SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);                
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
sda.Dispose();
command.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();

object[,] ret = new object[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];
int rowCount = 0;
int colCount = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        ret[rowCount, colCount] = col.ColumnName;
        colCount++;
    }
    rowCount++;
}
...
return ret;
```

Are either the Python or C# codes sub-optimal? For example, should I use `SQLiteDataReader` instead of `SQLiteDataAdapter`? Would appreciate any thoughts.

The result sets themselves are pretty small, in some cases just a single number, so I wouldn't have thought that ExcelDNA was adding headroom to the process. Sample Python query take about 15 seconds, whereas C# up to 1 minute.

Finally how would amending the `PRAGMA` settings affect performance? Any suggestions on some generic settings given my top priority is the speed of the query?

Also, any suggestions on how to actually implement these settings in Python, C# or persist them would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't purging the datatable, SQL command or connection properly. Once I stuck the `Dispose` methods into a `finally` block, the response of the C# code increased drastically and outperforming Python in most cases.